# When iterating with {{#each}} how to not include the entry in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

The person I'm designing this app for requested that she be able to make a email list of people with birthdays within the next 7 days. One of the fields in the collection is Bdate in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I decided to make a registerHelper with a simple algorithm that determines if the birthdate is one that fit the request:

```
Template.registerHelper('calculateBirthday', function(bdate) {
  var birthDate = new Date(bdate);
  var current = new Date();
  var diff = current - birthDate; // Difference in milliseconds
  var sevenDayDiff = Math.ceil(diff/31557600000) - (diff/31557600000);
  if (sevenDayDiff <= 0.01995183087435)
    return date;
  else
    return false;
});
```

The template would have a table that lists the birthdates that are the ones to get for the email list:

```
<table class="bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Birthday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each QueryBirthday}}
    <tr>
    <tr>{{FullName}}</tr>
      <td>{{calculateBirthday Bdate}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The problem with this is that it prints all the names with mostly blank birthdates. The algorithm works fine, but how to tell Meteor to only include those names and birthdates that 'should' be on the list?

Comment: make a helper that returns true/false and wrap each line in `{{#if}}`

Comment: My assumption is that `QueryBirthday` is a helper function that queries a collection using the `find` method. It sounds like all you need to do is limit the results to people that have values in the `Bdate` field. Is that correct? If so, can you include *that* helper function as well?

Comment: @BrianShamblen All the people have birthdate values in the Bdate field. Yes, the helper is just returning an array of documents that represent a subset of the whole collection.

Comment: @pikausp I'm not sure if I follow when you say to make the helper return true/false. My helper is returning part of the collection for spacebars to iterate over. Could you clarify?

Comment: @MatthewMoon check Karthik's answer, that's what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to hide unwanted items is

```
<table class="bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Birthday</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {{#each QueryBirthday}}
        {{#if calculateBirthday Bdate}}
           <tr>
              <td>{{FullName}}</td>
              <td>{{calculateBirthday Bdate}}</td>
           </tr>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know how your application works, but like other people who commented on your question, I would filter and send only the required results from server to client.

Comment: Would there be a way to say something like: {{#if calculateBirthday Bdate 7}}. In other words, not just check a boolean, but the resulting value from the register helper itself?